# How to swap domain names hosted on the same server

Tags: wordpress, dns, server, cpanel, domain-name

I have two different wordpress sites(Site A and Site B). I need to interchange the domain names of the two sites. That is, I want SiteB.com to point Site A and SiteA.com to point Site B.

Can you please give me direction on how to do this?

Do I need to take care of any domain related settings in cpanel?

Both the domains are hosted on the same server. They are hosted on shared IP hosting.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

change sitea.com to sitea.out

change siteb.com to sitea.com

change sitea.out to siteb.com

Then update your wordpress to use the new domain names in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the IP address for each site thats all.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all details then change the name-server or contact to person who book your domain.

Comment: I've booked the domains and I have name server details. Is interchanging name servers enough?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that both websites are hosting on same servers but you want to interchange the contents for both websites, I suggest you to perform the following steps:

- First secure full backup of both accounts.. just for safety.
- Create a backup directory under "site A" and move all contents to backup folder.
- Create a database backup for "site A"
- Now copy all the contents of "Site B" to "site A"
- Create a new database under site A account and restore site B database under newly created database
- Now update your site A's wp-config.php (which was migrated from site B) file to use new database.
- You will also need to update you WordPress URL. Refer following URL to change your WordPress URL from Site B to Site A:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Now move all contents from Site B to other place and copy the contents of Site A (which you backed up earlier) to Site B. Create a new database in Site B and restore the backup which you take earlier. Update your wp-config.php file to use new database. Follow the link to update your WordPress blog/site URL.